# Java Sound API unable to stop recording on a button click from UI of a web Application

Tags: java, api, audio

I am using Java Sound API for creating a Web Application .User Interface(UI) has a button which on click starts recording the speech ,the recorded audio is saved in an audio file (.wav ext) .UI also has a play button which accesses the same audio file and plays the recording back.
Currently I am recording the audio for a specified duration which is hardcoded in my application or getting passed from UI as a parameter while the recording starts.But now the requirement is to stop the recording on click of a button on UI.

Now the issue is while capturing the audio I am opening a targetline using below code :

---

public void capture(int record_time)
{

```
        try {
         AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
         DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
         if(!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info))
         {
             System.out.println("Line not supported");}

         final TargetDataLine targetDataLine =        (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);

         targetDataLine.open();
          targetDataLine.start();
         Thread thread = new Thread()
         {
             @Override public void run() 

             {
                 AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine);
                 File audioFile = new File(fileName);

                System.out.println("Recording is going to get saved in path :::: "+ audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
                 try{
                     AudioSystem.write(audioStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, audioFile);
                 }
                 catch (IOException e){
                     e.printStackTrace();
                 }
                 System.out.println("Stopped Recording");
             }
         };
         thread.start();
         Thread.sleep(record_time*1000); 
         targetDataLine.stop();
         targetDataLine.close();
        System.out.println("Ended recording test");
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
          System.err.println("Line unavailable: " + e);
          System.exit(-2);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

}

---

Above code will stop recording once the record time is elapsed.

But I want another method like below which when invoked from jsp (stop button click) should be able to get the same targetline object which is responsible for current recording and stop the current recording.

Below code does not work for me and recording goes on

---

```
public void stop(){
    try{
        System.out.println("stop :: in stop");
         AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
         DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
         if(!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info))
         {
             System.out.println("Line not supported");}

         final TargetDataLine targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info);
         System.out.println("stop Recording....");

         System.out.println("targetDataLine.getLineInfo() in stop:::::::"+targetDataLine.getLineInfo());
         System.out.println("targetDataLine.isActive() in stop:::::::"+targetDataLine.isActive());
         System.out.println("targetDataLine.isOpen() in stop:::::::"+targetDataLine.isOpen());

         targetDataLine.stop();
         targetDataLine.close();
    }
     catch (Exception e) {
          System.err.println("Line unavailable: " + e);
     }
}
```

---

Please suggest some resolution.

One more thing that might ..not sure but might has some role to play is the way I am calling these methods from my servlet ..below is the code....

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

```
    String action = request.getParameter("buttonName");
    String record_time = request.getParameter("time");
    System.out.println("action:::"+action +"time in minutes:::"+ record_time);
    int record_time_int =(Integer.parseInt(record_time));
    String fileName = "studentXYZ.wav";

    System.out.println("action:::"+action +"----wavfile:::"+fileName+"time in minutes:::"+ record_time);

    Recorder01 record = new Recorder01();


    if (action != null && (action.equalsIgnoreCase("Capture")) ){

        record.capture(fileName, action,record_time_int);
                request.setAttribute("fileName", fileName);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("/recordAudio.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    else if (action != null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("play")) {
        Recorder01 playsound = new Recorder01();
        playsound.play(fileName);
        System.out.println("finished playing recording");
        request.setAttribute("fileName", fileName);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/recordAudio.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }

    else if(action!=null && action.equalsIgnoreCase("Stop")){
        System.out.println("stop recording called");
        record.stop();
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/recordAudio.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
}
```

Comment: Make `targetDataLine` a instance field variable which can the be accessed from `stop`...

Comment: I tried doing that but I am getting targetline using  below code snippet and in my capture method I m using targetline in an inner class hence it has to be declared as final.And so is the reason cant make it instance variable .  AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 8, 2, 4, 44100, false);
    DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
    try{
      targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info) ;
    }
   catch(LineUnavailableException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
   }

Comment: So?  Move `targetDataLine` out of the method and declare it as a class/instance field, then both methods can access it

Comment: AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 22050, 16, 2, 4, 22050, false);
   DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
   private final TargetDataLine targetDataLine  = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info) ;                                                             I made it instance variable like above , now "  private final TargetDataLine targetDataLine  = (TargetDataLine)AudioSystem.getLine(info) " shows unhandled Exception for LineUnavailableException. how do I catch this exception at class level declaration.

Comment: Don't create it, just declare it

Comment: I declared it at class level using below code snippet and now it throws Nullpointer in stop method. and the recording doesnt stop.      AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 5512, 16, 2, 4, 5512, false);
      DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
   TargetDataLine targetDataLine ;                                                             targetDataline is getting created in capture method.I am calling capture method before calling stop.

Comment: My "guess" you're shadowing your variables

Answer (score 0):

```
private TargetDataLine targetDataLine;

public void capture() {

    if (targetDataLine == null) {

        try {
            AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED, 44100, 16, 2, 4, 44100, false);
            DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, format);
            if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
                System.out.println("Line not supported");
            }

            targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);

            targetDataLine.open();
            targetDataLine.start();
            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    AudioInputStream audioStream = new AudioInputStream(targetDataLine);
                    File audioFile = new File(fileName);

                    System.out.println("Recording is going to get saved in path :::: " + audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    try {
                        AudioSystem.write(audioStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, audioFile);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Stopped Recording");
                }
            };
            thread.start();
        } catch (LineUnavailableException e) {
            System.err.println("Line unavailable: " + e);
            System.exit(-2);
        }
    }
}

public void stop() {
    if (targetDataLine != null) {
        System.out.println("stop :: in stop");
        targetDataLine.stop();
        targetDataLine.close();
        targetDataLine = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Now it doesnt not throw any error as we have handled it,but targetDataLine in stop method is still null and it is not able to stop recording on button click. One more thing that might ..not sure but might has some role is the way I am calling these methods from my servlet.

Comment: The only reason `targetDataLine` would be `null` in `stop` is if it was never assigned a value in `start`...

Comment: I have put sysouts in capture ..and they shows targetDataLine is not null in capture method.

Comment: You're not shadowing the variable?

Comment: How are these methods been called?  Via a applet?

Comment: No, I'm not shadowing it. Buttons are invoked from jsp -->servlet- -->Methods  I have modifed my question to share the servlet code.could you please have a look.

Comment: It works perfectly but you forgot to start the thread...I added `thread.start();` into your code.